# vsts - devops best way to run tests on dynamic vm

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, azure-devops

my vsts continuous integration flow is:

1. create dynamic linux vm
2. copy the latest builds artifact to the new dynamic vm
3. running some scripts on the new dynamic vm
4. runing tests on the new dynamic vm
5. destroy the dynamic vm

im using Azure RG Deployment to create the dynamic vm from arm template,

but im not sure about the best practice how to copy the latest artifact and running script and tests on the new vm

(dynamic vm cant be be in my Service connections list and the ps tasks in vsts not works in linux)

so how to access to my latest artifact and copy it to dynamic vm and run scripts and tests on the dynamic vm using vsts azure devops ?

Comment: Can you containerize this process? Containers would be a far better way of accomplishing this objective.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Azure File Copy" -task to copy files to virtual machine and afterwards you can use "PowerShell on Target Machines" -task to run PowerShell -scripts (you didn't specify what kind of scripts, but that is how in case of PowerShell -scripts).

What kind of tests are you talking about? You should check the Azure DevOps task gallery for test tasks that come out of the box.

Then you can use the same Azure RG Deployment -task to remove the whole vm/resource group).

Comment: hi thanks! "Azure File Copy" and all "PowerShell on Target Machines" -task works only on win machine

Comment: Oh sorry missed that. Then you could perhaps use "Copy Files Over SSH" and "SSH" -tasks?

Comment: but the vm need to be in "Service connections" list to use "Copy Files Over SSH" and because its create dynamic its cant be there and i even dont have the ip of the dynamic machine  i only have the resource group and storage account

Comment: Oh well if the OTB tasks wont work in your case I guess you have to use the fallback choice of writing your own PowerShell -script which does the copying and executing scripts.